# How do I insert output from xml.nodes() into a table?

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008, nodes

I am new to sql server and I am trying to insert rows into a database from XML documents.  I have done some research and managed to get XML into a rowset using the XML nodes function.  However, I have no idea what to do next.  How do I insert this rowset into an existing table with the same column names?

Below is what I have so far, can anyone help with where I go next?

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
N'  <Products>
        <Product>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>Amy</name>
        <age>25</age>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <id>7</id>
            <name>Vicky</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </Product>
    </Products>'

SELECT  doc.col.value('id[1]',      'nvarchar(10)')     id
    ,   doc.col.value('name[1]',    'varchar(100)')     name 
    ,   doc.col.value('age[1]',     'nvarchar(10)')     age 
FROM    @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') doc(col)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the output of the `SELECT` statement to the `INSERT` statement of the table into which you would like the data to be populated.

*Suggestions*:

- You can change the datatype used for *id* and *age* nodes from *nvarchar(10)* to **`int`** assuming that both fields should represent numbers.

*Script*:

```
CREATE  TABLE dbo.mytable
(   
        id      INT         NOT NULL
    ,   name    VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL
    ,   age     INT         NULL
)

DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = 
N'  <Products>
        <Product>
        <id>4</id>
        <name>John</name>
        <age>25</age>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <id>7</id>
            <name>Jane</name>
            <age>40</age>
        </Product>
        <Product>
            <id>6</id>
            <name>Jill</name>
            <age></age>
        </Product>
    </Products>'

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (id, name, age)
SELECT  doc.col.value('id[1]',      'int')      id
    ,   doc.col.value('name[1]',    'varchar(100)')     name 
    ,   doc.col.value('age[1]',     'int')      age 
FROM    @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') doc(col);

SELECT * FROM dbo.mytable;
```

*Output*:

```
id  name    age
--  ------  ---
4   John    25
7   Jane    40
6   Jill    0
```

Comment: was wondering if there is a short hand way of doing this?  There will be cases where I have lots of fields and lots of nodes to match up, when essentially I just want each node to be inserted into each corresponding field in the row.  All my node names and all my field names will be the same.

Comment: also, do I have to go through and specify the field type for each one?  Can it not just enter into the database...

Answer (score 1):

You might need this

```
INSERT INTO YourTableName(Id,name,age)
SELECT
 doc.col.value('id[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') id
,doc.col.value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)') name 
,doc.col.value('age[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') age 
FROM @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') doc(col)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO Table
(
col1
, col2
, col3
)
SELECT
 doc.col.value('id[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
,doc.col.value('name[1]', 'varchar(100)')
,doc.col.value('age[1]', 'nvarchar(10)')
FROM 
    @xml.nodes('/Products/Product') doc(col)
```