# Is it bad practice to use cfquery inside cfloop?

Tags: coldfusion, cfquery, cfloop

I am having an array of structure. I need to insert all the rows from that array to a table.
So I have simply used `cfquery` inside `cfloop` to insert into the database.

Some people suggested me not to use cfquery inside cfloop as each time it will make a new connection to the database.

But in my case Is there any way I can do this without using cfloop inside cfquery?

Comment: If you have set your datasource to maintain connections it will not create a new connection for each iteration.

Comment: @Miguel-F: Can you please explain me in bit detail? How to set datasource to maintain connection.

Comment: Why not use `cfloop` inside `cfquery` to build the `INSERT` statement?

Comment: There is an option to "maintain connection" in the datasource settings from the ColdFusion administrator page. You need to click the "Advanced Settings" button to see the additional options.

Answer (score 2):

Its not so much about maintaining connections as hitting the server with 'n' requests to insert or update data for every iteration in the cfloop. This will seem ok with a test of a few records, but then when you throw it into production and your client pushes your application to look around a couple of hundred rows then you're going to hit the database server a couple of hundred times as well.

As Scott suggests you should see about looping around to build a single query rather than the multiple hits to the database. Looping around inside the cfquery has the benefit that you can use cfqueryparam, but if you can trust the data ie. it has already been sanatised, you might find it easier to use something like cfsavecontent to build up your query and output the string inside the cfquery at the end.

Comment: Yes the same issue there are thousands of records are there in the db, This might be a good option to dynamically generate all the querystrings at a time and pass it to cfquery.

Comment: Agreed on minimizing database calls. However, I do not see any benefit to building a sql string instead of using `cfqueryparam`. You lose out on pre-database validation, not to mention the burden of ensuring *all* data is properly sanitized (single quotes are handled, etcetera) is now data on you, instead of being able to rely on well tested jdbc methods. IMO you are much better off sticking with `cfqueryparam`.

Comment: Good advice, other than the 2100 limit if he uses SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I have used both the query inside loop and loop inside query method.  While having the loop inside the query is theoretically faster, it is not always the case.  You have to try each method and see what works best in your situation.

Here is the syntax for loop inside query, using oracle for the sake of picking a database.

```
insert into table
(field1, field2, etc)
select null, null, etc
from dual
where 1 = 2
<cfloop>
union
select <cfqueryparam value="#value1#">
, <cfqueryparam value="#value2#">
etc
from dual
</cfloop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the database, convert your array of structures to XML, then pass that as a single parameter to a stored procedure.

In the stored procedure, do an INSERT INTO SELECT, where the SELECT statement selects data from the XML packet. You could insert hundreds or thousands of records with a single INSERT statement this way.

[Here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10396721/how-do-i-insert-output-from-xml-nodes-into-a-table).

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit to how many `<CFQUERY><cfloop>`... iterations you can do when using `<cfqueryparam>`. This is also vendor specific. If you do not know how many records you will be generating, it is best to remove `<cfqueryparam>`, if it is safe to do so. Make sure your data is coming from trusted sources & is sanitised. This approach can save huge amounts of processing time, because it is only make one call to the database server, unlike an outer loop.

Comment: I believe the question uses the other nesting direction ... he has `cfquery` within `cfloop`.